# Obtaining a value from a log file with bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to get the values from a log file, for the last 24 hours.

```
2015-10-13 09:17:30 INFO Average 1min EPS: 1040
2015-10-13 09:18:30 INFO Average 1min EPS: 1235
2015-10-13 09:19:30 INFO Average 1min EPS: 1020
2015-10-13 09:20:30 INFO Average 1min EPS: 1202
2015-10-13 09:21:30 INFO Average 1min EPS: 990
```

All I need is the value. I am hoping I can obtain the last 24 hours at the time of the script execution.

My ultimate goal is to get the "Average 1min EPS: ", add all the values, and get the average EPS total.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem is selecting the lines that are within the last day (*)

Use `date` to find the starting timestamp:

```
yesterday=$(date -d "yesterday" "+%F %T")
```

Then, awk is a handy tool to compare strings

```
awk -v d="$yesterday" '($1 " " $2) > d {print}' file.log
```

Then, you only want the last field from each line

```
awk -v d="$yesterday" '($1 " " $2) > d {print $NF}' file.log
```

If you only want the sum

```
awk -v d="$yesterday" '($1 " " $2) > d {sum+=$NF} END {print sum}' file.log
```

(*) one day is not necessarily 24 hours